# python make fixed frame while bigger canvas inside

Tags: python, tkinter

width or\and height = size

I have `frame 300x300` and a `canvas 600x600` (canvas inside the frame).

I want fixed size of the `frame`, because if I change `canvas` size -> my frame size becoming equal to width and height of the canvas! How to make fixed size of the `frame` so my `canvas` will no be shown?

```
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow():
  def __init__(self):
    self.canvas_width = 600   # more than frame width
    self.canvas_height = 600  # more than frame height

    self.frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=300) # should be fixed in the window
    self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg='bisque', width=self.canvas_width, height=self.canvas_height,
                         scrollregion=(0, 0, self.canvas_width, self.canvas_height))
    self.frame.propagate(False)

    self.hbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    self.hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    self.hbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

    self.vbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=VERTICAL)
    self.vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    self.vbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

    # self.canvas.config(width=300, height=300)
    self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.hbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set)
    self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.scroll_start)
    self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.scroll_move)

    self.grid(self.canvas)

  def grid(self, canvas):
    for line in range(0, self.canvas_height, 10):
        canvas.create_line([(line, 0), (line, self.canvas_height)], fill='#d9d9d9')
    for line in range(0, self.canvas_width, 10):
        canvas.create_line([(0, line), (self.canvas_width, line)], fill='#d9d9d9')

  def scroll_start(self, event):
    self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

  def scroll_move(self, event):
    self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry('850x700')
  MainWindow()
  root.mainloop()
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umx9b.png)

Comment: `self.frame.propagate(False)`

Comment: @furas but it doesnt gives inner canvas grow, I have canvas width 1000 but it doesnt show it is

Comment: @furas I have canvas_width = 1000 (frame width = 300) and I have this (see pic in the question)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You asked how to keep `Frame` size and `propagate(False)` keeps this size. And it shows scrollbars which let you scroll canvas - at least on Linux. I don't understand why you have red squares on image.

Comment: BTW: if you change code in question then describe it. Now my first comment seems useless because you have it in code - and it may looks like you had it at the beginning.

Comment: why do you only want part of the canvas to be visible? If you're simply wanting to be able to draw items bigger the canvas, you don't have to make the canvas big. Internally the canvas is 64000x64000 no matter what the physical size is.

Comment: @BryanOakley I want some part to be visible like on a googlemap and user can drag it. When I specify canvas 1000 1000 (for example) and I have frame 300x300, my frame is resizing with canvas and become very big (1000 1000 etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how canvases work. You do not need to create a large canvas. The physical size contains a much larger virtual canvas.  In fact, definitely do *not* want a bigger canvas to be partially hidden by a smaller frame, because part of the canvas would be hidden by the frame.

In other words, if you have a canvas that is 300x300 on screen, you can still draw in it as if it was 600x600 or 6000x6000 or 60000x60000.

You do this by configuring the `scrollregion` of the canvas, which tells the canvas how much space you plan to draw in. For example, to have a canvas that is 300x300 but draw as if it were 600x600, you would configure it like this:

```
canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,599,599))
```

Here's a simple example showing how that works. Notice that we are placing objects in the corners, and it's possible to scroll around to see all four corners.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, background="black")
ysb = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview, orient="vertical")
xsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.xview, orient="horizontal")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=ysb.set, xscrollcommand=xsb.set)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

# designate that we want to draw in a 600x600 virtual canvas
canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,599,599))

canvas.create_line(0,0,599,599, width=1, fill="white")
canvas.create_line(0,599, 599, 0, width=1, fill="white")
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,19,19, fill="red")
canvas.create_rectangle(579, 579, 599,599, fill="red")
canvas.create_rectangle(579, 0, 599, 19, fill="red")
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 579, 19, 599, fill="red")
canvas.create_rectangle(290,290, 310, 310, fill="green")

root.mainloop()
```